# Чем обусловлена линейная сложность функции list::size()?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, stl

В действительности вопроса даже два. К некоторому для себя удивлению узнал, что временная сложность получения к-ва айтемов списка `std::list::size()` - линейная

> C++98. Complexity: Up to linear. [Источник](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/size/)

Не совсем понятно, чем это обусловлено. Для чего каждый раз подсчитывать свои айтемы?

И если в этом была необходимость в ранних стандартах, то за счет каких компромиссов удалось достичь гарантии константности в стандарте новом?

> C++11. Complexity: Constant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Это следствие стародавнего "конфликта интересов" между функцими `std::list::size()` и `std::list::splice()`.

Если делается частичный `splice()` из одного `std::list` в другой с требованием константного времени выполнения такого `splice()` (т.е. просто перецепить крайние элементы диапазона из одного списка в другой), то тогда невозможно будет сразу знать новые размеры контейнера-источника и контейнера-получателя, т.к. неизвестно сколько элементов перецепилось. Поэтому требование *константного* по времени `splice()` ведет к требованию *линейного* по времени `size()` - элементы в обоих контейнерах придется заново пересчитывать.

Если же наоборот потребовать константности времени `size()` (т.е. фактически потребовать хранимый размер), то тогда придется согласиться на более медленный `splice()`, который в вышеупомянутой ситуации за линейное время будет вычислять новые размеры контейнеров.

В С++98 этот вопрос был оставлен открытым. Реализациям разрешалось выбирать, где по их мнению константное время важнее - в `size()` или в `splice()`.

В С++11 решили принять волевое решение: делаем хранимый размер, гарантируем `size()` за константное время и, так уж и быть, соглашаемся на линейное время в `splice()`.

Именно этим и объясняется разница между С++98 и С++11.

P.S. Реализация стандартной библиотеки С++ в GCC изначально пошла по пути быстрого `splice()` и медленного `size()`. После того, как С++11 настоял на ином варианте, GCC исправил реализацию своего `std::list`, но тут же наткнулся на бинарную несовместимость версий библиотек из-за добавления нового поля в `std::list`. Изменение было тут же откачено, и по сей день `std::list` в GCC не соответствует требованиям С++11. `std::list::size()` там линеен.